# Tennis match scheduling

Tags: algorithm, prolog, scheduling, clpfd

There are a limited number of players and a limited number of tennis courts.  At each round, there can be at most as many matches as there are courts.
Nobody plays 2 rounds without a break.  Everyone plays a match against everyone else.
Produce the schedule that takes as few rounds as possible.  (Because of the rule that there must a break between rounds for everyone, there can be a round without matches.)
The output for 5 players and 2 courts could be:

```
 |  1   2   3   4   5
-|------------------- 
2|  1   - 
3|  5   3   - 
4|  7   9   1   - 
5|  3   7   9   5   -
```

In this output the columns and rows are the player-numbers, and the numbers inside the matrix are the round numbers these two players compete.

The problem is to find an algorithm which can do this for larger instances in a feasible time.  We were asked to do this in Prolog, but (pseudo-) code in any language would be useful.

My first try was a greedy algorithm, but that gives results with too many rounds.
Then I suggested an iterative deepening depth-first search, which a friend of mine implemented, but that still took too much time on instances as small as 7 players.

(This is from an old exam question. No one I spoke to had any solution.)

Comment: "Nobody I spoke to found a solution for this question" this sound strange, because there is very easy solution, but not good one of course.

Comment: In your example ... Why nobody plays at rounds 2,4,6,8?

Comment: I forgot to say that is was specified in the question that the 6 players 2 courts case had to run in under a minute. Which nobody managed. A few people found solutions for the question, but nobody found a solution which could do it under a minute. (@belisarius, nobody plays at round 2 because players 1,2,3,4 played at round 1 so they have to take a break the next round, so there is nobody free to have a match with player 5 in round 2)

Comment: @belisarius because one player has to have a break. Players 1, 2, 3, 4 played at first round and need break. 5th can't play alone.

Comment: @Ingdas what is length of single round?

Comment: You can think of all matches as equal in length. All matches and minimum breaks take 1 time-unit. And each round is 1 time-unit.

Comment: @Ingdas Use Genetic Algorithms and under that you have to work with the permutations of the players to produce a good/smart solution depending on the rules that you specify in your CalcFitness for each Chromosome (here, a chromosome stands for a full schedule). So, Generate initial random schedules at first and let the GA does the work for you. I think this can be solved in under one minute on a good hardware.

Comment: @LordCover genetic algorithm is enormous overhead here. Simple brute force would work faster.

Comment: @Ingdas the obvious very stupid but very generic solution is to schedule rounds in **any** fashion. Then check which are incompatible and but break between them.

Comment: Did you have to write working prolog on an exam paper? Did they enter your programs into the computer and check them? I'm very curious. Unless this can be done in 4 lines of prolog or less, I wonder how they would mark this question, if it was on paper.

Comment: The exam was on a computer without internet access but with SWI-Prolog so you could debug your own programs. We had 4 hours for 2 problems, which were supposedly equal in difficulty. So we were expected to work 2 hours at this one. Most people solved the other one, but no one fully solved this one. But I still don't see how we were supposed to do it. Maybe I was brute-forcing the wrong way.

Comment: @Ingdas:  What was the minimum number of rounds for the 6-player 2-court problem?

Comment: Is there a general math solution for finding the minimum number of rounds with X-players and Y-courts without solving the complete schedule?

Comment: @oosterwal, I think the minimum number was somewhere in the problem statement, but as I implemented a non-optimal algorithm on the exam itself and had troubles with the 5/2 case, I don't remember the minimum number of turns for 6/2. I have no clue if there is a way to calculate the minimum number of rounds. There is a lower bound of p*(p+1)/(2*fields) with p the number of players but it's obvious that that bound is too low.

Comment: A solution in Prolog should be much more concise and elegant than in an imperative language, since one has backtracking for free.  I'm offering a bounty for a correct Prolog answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Preface

In Prolog, **CLP(FD) constraints** are the right choice for solving such scheduling tasks.

See **[clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)** for more information.

In this case, I suggest using the powerful [`global_cardinality/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Arithmetic_002dLogical-Constraints.html#Arithmetic_002dLogical-Constraints) constraint to restrict the number of **occurrences** of each round, depending on the number of available courts. We can use *iterative deepening* to find the minimal number of admissible rounds.

Freely available Prolog systems suffice to solve the task satisfactorily. Commercial-grade systems will run dozens of times faster.

## Variant 1: Solution with SWI-Prolog

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

tennis(N, Courts, Rows) :-
        length(Rows, N),
        maplist(same_length(Rows), Rows),
        transpose(Rows, Rows),
        Rows = [[_|First]|_],
        chain(First, #<),
        length(_, MaxRounds),
        numlist(1, MaxRounds, Rounds),
        pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Rounds, Counts),
        Counts ins 0..Courts,
        foldl(triangle, Rows, Vss, Dss, 0, _),
        append(Vss, Vs),
        global_cardinality(Vs, Pairs),
        maplist(breaks, Dss),
        labeling([ff], Vs).

triangle(Row, Vs, Ds, N0, N) :-
        length(Prefix, N0),
        append(Prefix, [-|Vs], Row),
        append(Prefix, Vs, Ds),
        N #= N0 + 1.

breaks([]).
breaks([P|Ps]) :- maplist(breaks_(P), Ps), breaks(Ps).

breaks_(P0, P) :- abs(P0-P) #> 1.
```

Sample query: 5 players on 2 courts:

```
?- time(tennis(5, 2, Rows)), maplist(writeln, Rows).
% 827,838 inferences, 0.257 CPU in 0.270 seconds (95% CPU, 3223518 Lips)
[-,1,3,5,7]
[1,-,5,7,9]
[3,5,-,9,1]
[5,7,9,-,3]
[7,9,1,3,-]
```

The specified task, **6 players on 2 courts**, solved well within the time limit of 1 minute:

```
?- time(tennis(6, 2, Rows)),
   maplist(format("~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+\n"), Rows).
% 6,675,665 inferences, 0.970 CPU in 0.977 seconds (99% CPU, 6884940 Lips)
  -  1  3  5  7 10
  1  -  6  9 11  3
  3  6  - 11  9  1
  5  9 11  -  2  7
  7 11  9  2  -  5
 10  3  1  7  5  -
```

Further example: 7 players on 5 courts:

```
?- time(tennis(7, 5, Rows)),
   maplist(format("~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+\n"), Rows).
% 125,581,090 inferences, 17.476 CPU in 18.208 seconds (96% CPU, 7185927 Lips)
  -  1  3  5  7  9 11
  1  -  5  3 11 13  9
  3  5  -  9  1  7 13
  5  3  9  - 13 11  7
  7 11  1 13  -  5  3
  9 13  7 11  5  -  1
 11  9 13  7  3  1  -
```

## Variant 2: Solution with SICStus Prolog

With the following additional definitions for compatibility, the *same* program also runs in SICStus Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(between)).

:- op(700, xfx, ins).

Vs ins D :- maplist(in_(D), Vs).

in_(D, V) :- V in D.

chain([], _).
chain([L|Ls], Pred) :-
        chain_(Ls, L, Pred).

chain_([], _, _).
chain_([L|Ls], Prev, Pred) :-
        call(Pred, Prev, L),
        chain_(Ls, L, Pred).

pairs_keys_values(Ps, Ks, Vs) :- keys_and_values(Ps, Ks, Vs).

foldl(Pred, Ls1, Ls2, Ls3, S0, S) :-
        foldl_(Ls1, Ls2, Ls3, Pred, S0, S).

foldl_([], [], [], _, S, S).
foldl_([L1|Ls1], [L2|Ls2], [L3|Ls3], Pred, S0, S) :-
        call(Pred, L1, L2, L3, S0, S1),
        foldl_(Ls1, Ls2, Ls3, Pred, S1, S).

time(Goal) :-
        statistics(runtime, [T0|_]),
        call(Goal),
        statistics(runtime, [T1|_]),
        T #= T1 - T0,
        format("% Runtime: ~Dms\n", [T]).
```

Major difference: SICStus, being a commercial-grade Prolog that ships with a serious CLP(FD) system, is **much faster** than SWI-Prolog in this use case and others like it.

The specified task, 6 players on 2 courts:

```
?-   time(tennis(6, 2, Rows)),
     maplist(format("~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+\n"), Rows).
% Runtime: 34ms (!)
  -  1  3  5  7 10
  1  -  6 11  9  3
  3  6  -  9 11  1
  5 11  9  -  2  7
  7  9 11  2  -  5
 10  3  1  7  5  -
```

The larger example:

```
| ?- time(tennis(7, 5, Rows)),
   maplist(format("~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+~t~w~3+\n"), Rows).
% Runtime: 884ms
  -  1  3  5  7  9 11
  1  -  5  3  9  7 13
  3  5  -  1 11 13  7
  5  3  1  - 13 11  9
  7  9 11 13  -  3  1
  9  7 13 11  3  -  5
 11 13  7  9  1  5  -
```

## Closing remarks

In both systems, `global_cardinality/3` allows you to specify options that alter the propagation strength of the global cardinality constraint, enabling weaker and potentially more efficient filtering. Choosing the right options for a specific example may have an even larger impact than the choice of Prolog system.

Comment: Wow, that's a very interesting library!  Thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately, your example queries return `false` on my `SWI-Prolog version 5.8.0 for i386`.  Do you know why?  Maybe this will be a hint: the first query returned `false` after 5544 inferences, the second and third after 42 inferences.

Comment: Upgrade to a more recent version; transpose/2 was previously only exported by library(upgraphs), but library(clpfd) (in more recent versions) exports a different implementation of transpose/2 that works on lists instead of graphs. Alternatively, you can implement your own version of transpose/2 or copy the predicate source from library(clpfd). In general, if you want to know why query Q fails, try the query ?- gtrace, Q.

Comment: I've copied `transpose/2` from the more recent version of SWI-Prolog and it works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: In fact, you can replace your whole clpfd.pl by a version from the SWI development repository; the current git version supports the "consistency(value)" option in global_cardinality/3, which implements a weaker form of consistency that performs faster on many examples, including the above query "tennis(7,5,Rs)" which finds a solution in less than 10 seconds with this option.

Answer (score 12):

This is very similar to the [Traveling Tournament Problem](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/TOURN/), which is about scheduling football teams. In TTP, they can find the optimal solution up to only 8 teams. Anyone who breaks an ongoing record of 10 or more teams, has it a lot easier to get published in a research journal.

It is NP hard and the trick is to use meta-heuristics, such as tabu search, simulated annealing, ... instead of brute force or branch and bound.

Take a look [my implementation](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm/tree/master/drools-planner/drools-planner-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/planner/examples/travelingtournament) with [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (open source, java).
[Here are the constraints](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm/blob/master/drools-planner/drools-planner-examples/src/main/resources/org/drools/planner/examples/travelingtournament/solver/smart/smartTravelingTournamentScoreRules.drl), it should be straightforward to replace that with constraints such as *Nobody plays 2 rounds without a break.*

Comment: It's possible that this is NP-Hard but I doubt that since all NP-problems I know of have more inputs then just 2 integers. Also, we had to guarantee the exact solution so heuristic methods were not really an option. The Drools Planner solution could work but I'd like a solution which I can understand how it works without advanced libraries.

Comment: @Ingdas We can code an arbitrary number of intergers into a single integer.

Comment: Constraints like "Nobody plays 2 rounds without a break." (and maybe others he hasn't mentioned yet) also make it NP hard fast. To prove something is P hard is easy: show me the algorithm that performs in P. But vice versa?

Comment: If you want to avoid libraries, take a look at the keywords on wikipedia: branch and bound, simulated annealing, ...

Comment: @Ingdas Integer factorisation? :)

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I'd be lying if I said that upvoting you to break your current score of 6666 wasn't part of my motivation :) Great answer though!

Comment: :) I 'll let you know when I reach 666 twitter followers and got a bill of 666 € that I have split with someone ;)

Answer (score 5):

Each player must play at least n - 1 matches where n is the number of players. So the minimum of rounds is 2(n - 1) - 1, since every player needs to rest a match. The minimum is also bound by (n(n-1))/2 total matches divided by number of courts. Using the smallest of these two gives you the length of the optimal solution. Then it's a matter of coming up with a good lower estimating formula ((number of matches+rests remaining)/courts) and run [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

As Geoffrey said, I believe the problem is NP Hard, but meta-heuristics such as A* is very applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Python Solution:

```
import itertools

def subsets(items, count = None):
    if count is None:
        count = len(items)

    for idx in range(count + 1):
        for group in itertools.combinations(items, idx):
            yield frozenset(group)

def to_players(games):
    return [game[0] for game in games] + [game[1] for game in games]

def rounds(games, court_count):
    for round in subsets(games, court_count):
        players = to_players(round)
        if len(set(players)) == len(players):
            yield round

def is_canonical(player_count, games_played):
    played = [0] * player_count
    for players in games_played:
        for player in players:
            played[player] += 1

    return sorted(played) == played



def solve(court_count, player_count):
    courts = range(court_count)
    players = range(player_count)

    games = list( itertools.combinations(players, 2) )
    possible_rounds = list( rounds(games, court_count) )

    rounds_last = {}
    rounds_all = {}
    choices_last = {}
    choices_all = {}



    def update(target, choices, name, value, choice):
        try:
            current = target[name]
        except KeyError:
            target[name] = value
            choices[name] = choice
        else:
            if current > value:
                target[name] = value
                choices[name] = choice

    def solution(games_played, players, score, choice, last_players):
        games_played = frozenset(games_played)
        players = frozenset(players)

        choice = (choice, last_players)

        update(rounds_last.setdefault(games_played, {}), 
                choices_last.setdefault(games_played, {}), 
                players, score, choice)
        update(rounds_all, choices_all, games_played, score, choice)

    solution( [], [], 0, None, None)

    for games_played in subsets(games):
        if is_canonical(player_count, games_played):
            try:
                best = rounds_all[games_played]
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                for next_round in possible_rounds:
                    next_games_played = games_played.union(next_round)

                    solution( 
                        next_games_played, to_players(next_round), best + 2,
                        next_round, [])

                for last_players, score in rounds_last[games_played].items():
                    for next_round in possible_rounds:
                        if not last_players.intersection( to_players(next_round) ):
                            next_games_played = games_played.union(next_round)
                            solution( next_games_played, to_players(next_round), score + 1,
                                    next_round, last_players)

    all_games = frozenset(games)


    print rounds_all[ all_games ]
    round, prev = choices_all[ frozenset(games) ]
    while all_games:
        print "X ", list(round)
        all_games = all_games - round
        if not all_games:
            break
        round, prev = choices_last[all_games][ frozenset(prev) ]

solve(2, 6)
```

Output:

```
11
X  [(1, 2), (0, 3)]
X  [(4, 5)]
X  [(1, 3), (0, 2)]
X  []
X  [(0, 5), (1, 4)]
X  [(2, 3)]
X  [(1, 5), (0, 4)]
X  []
X  [(2, 5), (3, 4)]
X  [(0, 1)]
X  [(2, 4), (3, 5)]
```

This means it will take 11 rounds. The list shows the games to be played in the rounds in reverse order. (Although I think the same schedule works forwards and backwords.)
I'll come back and explain why I have the chance.

***Gets incorrect answers for one court, five players.***

Comment: Running this, I get the output "11". and that's it.  I don't know why. The value of games, at the end, is [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)], but the print rounds_all[ ] fails.

Comment: @Warren P, The 11 should be the minimum number of rounds required. (Is it correct?) It doesn't give the actual games played. I can add that but I didn't. games is a list of all the games that have to be played.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts, perhaps a solution...

Expanding the problem to X players and Y courts, I think we can safely say that when given the choice, we must select the players with the fewest completed matches, otherwise we run the risk of ending up with one player left who can only play every other week and we end up with many empty weeks in between.  Picture the case with 20 players and 3 courts.  We can see that during round 1 players 1-6 meet, then in round 2 players 7-12 meet, and in round 3 we could re-use players 1-6 leaving players 13-20 until later.  Therefor, I think our solution cannot be greedy and must balance the players.

With that assumption, here is a first attempt at a solution:

```
 1. Create master-list of all matches ([12][13][14][15][16][23][24]...[45][56].)
 2. While (master-list > 0) {
 3.     Create sub-list containing only eligible players (eliminate all players who played the previous round.)
 4.     While (available-courts > 0) {
 5.         Select match from sub-list where player1.games_remaining plus player2.games_remaining is maximized.
 6.         Place selected match in next available court, and 
 7.         decrement available-courts.
 8.         Remove selected match from master-list.
 9.         Remove all matches that contain either player1 or player2 from sub-list.
10.     } Next available-court
11.     Print schedule for ++Round.
12. } Next master-list
```

I can't prove that this will produce a schedule with the fewest rounds, but it should be close.  The step that may cause problems is #5 (select match that maximizes player's games remaining.)  I can imagine that there might be a case where it's better to pick a match that *almost* maximizes 'games_remaining' in order to leave more options in the following round.

The output from this algorithm would look something like:

```
Round    Court1    Court2
  1       [12]      [34]
  2       [56]       --
  3       [13]      [24]
  4        --        --
  5       [15]      [26]
  6        --        --
  7       [35]      [46]
  .         .         .
```

Close inspection will show that in round 5, if the match on Court2 had been [23] then match [46] could have been played during round 6.  That, however, doesn't guarantee that there won't be a similar issue in a later round.

I'm working on another solution, but that will have to wait for later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this matters, the "5 Players and 2 Courts" example data is missing three other matches: [1,3], [2,4] and [3,5]. Based on the instruction: "Everyone plays a match against everyone else."

Comment: No, player 1,3 played in round 5, maybe you read the diagram the wrong way ;)