# How to express the allDifferent/6 predicate?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

Let `allDifferent(A, B, C, D, E, F)` be true if and only if ∀*i*, *j* in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, the *i*-th and *j*-th arguments unify if and **only if** *i* = *j*.

Thus `allDifferent(3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9)` is false, but `allDifferent(3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 9)` is true.

How does one implement `allDifferent/6` in Prolog?

In particular, is there a way to express it that does not require listing the 6-choose-2 = 15 non-equalities `A` ≠ `B`, `A` ≠ `C`, ..., `E` ≠ `F` (or, rather, their Prolog rendition)?

Comment: Note that as it stands, your definition has to be `false` all the time! Here is why `∀ X, Y ∈ {A, B, C, D, E, F}` never holds: Consider `X = A, Y = A`!

Comment: @false: Nice pick!  I'll fix it pronto.  BTW, I included `swi-prolog` as a tag because, as I understand it, particular implementations may provide syntactic extensions that are not part of standard Prolog, and one such extension may apply to my question.

Comment: SWI is here as good as SICStus, YAP, B, IF, ... So it is not specific to SWI at all.

Comment: Consider `allDifferent(A, A, c, d, e, f)`. It's the same variable, isn't it? Still you expect it to fail.

Comment: @false, I'm not sure I understand your last comment.  FWIW, the first sentence of my post refers exclusively to the expression `allDifferent(A, B, C, D, E, F)`.

Comment: then how do you explain the case I gave? (The point of this is: at first glance, mathematical/logical notation looks more elegant than Prolog, but this is a case where in mathematical notation you would ultimately have to introduce another device like indices to express what can be expressed in Prolog without.)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22950154/772868).

Comment: @false: Point taken.  I've made a third attempt to get the problem statement right.  (I did this before I read your comment, but it seems like this third version goes in the direction you alluded.)

Comment: @false: BTW, I really appreciate your comments.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept that `allDifferent` receive a list of values (instead of six values) I can propose the following solution

```
isDifferent(_, []).

isDifferent(X, [H | T]) :-
  X \= H,
  isDifferent(X, T).

allDifferent([]).

allDifferent([H | T]) :-
  isDifferent(H, T),
  allDifferent(T).
```

**-- EDIT --**

As suggested by False, you can use `dif/2` instead of `\=` (if your Prolog provide it) so the main `isDifferent/2` can be

```
isDifferent(X, [H | T]) :-
  dif(X, H),
  isDifferent(X, T).
```

Anyway... hoping this is obvious... but if you really want a `allDifferent/6` instead a `allDifferent/1` that receive a list, you can define your `allDifferent/6` as follows

```
allDifferent(A, B, C, D, E, F) :-
  allDifferent([A, B, C, D, E, F]).
```

Comment: And ... why not use `dif/2`?

Comment: @false - because my gprolog doesn't provide it :(

Comment: Then use [`iso_dif/2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931/772868) which at least indicates with instantiation errors the situations where you are or might be wrong.