# Prolog: Tournament Schedule

Tags: prolog, constraints, schedule, clpfd, tournament

I am trying to automatically generate a schedule for a volleyball tournament I am organizing. It is mainly for fun. The rules are as follows:

- Teams that sign up consist of 2 players
- There are 36 such teams
- For a match, 3 such teams get put together to a "game team", so a match consists of 3 teams vs. 3 teams
- Every team plays 5 matches
- There are 3 courts than can be played at the same time
- Thus, a total of 10 rounds will be played (18 teams can play at the same time, so that is 36/2*5 rounds = 10 rounds)
- Games are officialled by teams

Additional constraints are:

- Every team officials at most once
- If possible, a team should not play with another team that it already played with before (if it played against, it is fine)
- There should not be more than 2 rounds break in between games for each team

Now I thought that this sounds like a problem that prolog is a good choice for. Unfortunately, I only have theoretical experience with it. It would be great if anybody could give me a good starting point with this, especially on how to fulfil constraints like "official at most once" and "every team plays 5 times". Also, a more compact representation of teams than

```
team(A).
team(B).
....
```

would be great. I already tried implementing this in Java,but came to the conclusion that it is not a well suited language. I'd like to do this in prolog now.

Comment: Prolog is indeed a great choice for such tasks. For a start, check out the very similar previous question about [tennis match scheduling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747498/tennis-match-scheduling) and your Prolog system's CLP(FD) documentation and sample programs.